# Undefined method in console?

Tags: ruby

Here comes another Codecademy question:

The following challenge has been presented.

> Define two methods in the editor:
>
> A greeter method that takes a single string parameter, name, and
>   returns a string greeting that person. (Make sure to use return and
>   don't use print or puts.)
>
> A by_three? method that takes a single integer parameter, number, and
>   returns true if that number is evenly divisible by three and false if
>   not. Remember, it's a Ruby best practice to end method names that
>   produce boolean values with a question mark.

The code I put in re: was..

```
def greeter(name)
   return "Greet #{name}"
end

def by_three?(x)
   if x % 3==0
      returns true
   else
      return false
end

greeter("Brant")
by_three?(6)
```

The console then gives me the following error:

```
Did you define your greeter method?
```

It seems like I have. Am I wrong?

Comment: ps: I realize the title should be undefined.. SORRY!

Comment: are you missing an end in `by_three?`

Comment: also, since you have a comparison, you don't need the if: `def by_three?(x); return x % 3 == 0; end` will do the same thing

Comment: thanks @JimDeville that took care of it. So in a boolean string, the second line basically says return it if it's true, otherwise return false?

Comment: Ruby returns the last expression by default, so if your last expression is a boolean test (`x % 3 == 0`), then the result (`true` or `false`) is returned. The `return` statement is redundant, but it seemed that you might need it per the instructions. tl;dr - `if foo; return true; else; return false; end` can always be condensed to `!!foo`, or if you don't _have_ to have a boolean, `foo` (anything other than `nil` or `false` is considered true)

Answer (score 1):

this would be it:

```
def greeter(name)
  "Greet #{name}"
end

def by_three?(x)
  x % 3 == 0
end

greeter("Brant") # => "Greet Brant"
by_three?(6) # => true
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you did not add "end" after your else statement. Here you go.

```
#For the greeter method, i decided to use this format

def greeter(name)
    return name
end

greeter("Hello Jane, good morning")

def by_three?(number)
    if number % 3 != 1
    return true
    else
        return false
    end #Add end here to end your statement
end

by_three?(5)
```